# Read and Display values from json using ajax

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript

Im trying to get data from a .json file that is recieved via post method to a external server, using ajax function and display it all on html (tags and data).
I can get the json data and display it via console log, however im not able to iterate over it, or simply display in on the html side.

I've tryed to create a public array and push the response to it, create a function, etc.. but looks like ajax function loads after it, and there's no data at all, then i've tried to concat a string with the values that i get on console, but no success.

I can't even get the actual data, only the tags. Im a little bit confused here. Can some one help me?

Here's my code and what it displays on console.

**component.hmt:**

```
<ul>
   <li>{{res}}</li>
</ul>
```

**component.ts**

```
public res = "";
ngOnInit() {

let settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "url": "ip/to/api",
          "context": this,  //added this
          "method": "POST",
          "data": "\"dataApi\"",
      };

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
console.log(response);
this.res = response; //added this
       for(let i in response)
       {
           //console.log(i);
           this.res += i + " - ";
           for(let j in response[i])
           {
               //console.log(j);
               this.res += j + " : \n ";
               for(let t in response[i][j])
               {
                   //console.log(t);
                   this.res += t +"\n";
               }
           }
       }
       console.log(this.res);
       return this.res;

   });
  }
}
```

Here's the output on console.log:
the thing is that on console log i can get all the tags : data, but i can't never get the data on res string to display.

> Console.log(response) : All the data i need to display.
>
> this.res : the tags without any data.

[image: console.log of json content and res string (withput any actual data, only the tags.. )]

Thanks in advance!!

Edit: Here's the output of {{res | json}} on html side:

> { "Challenges": [ { "Challenge.Closed": false,
>   "Challenge.EndSubmissionDate": "Sat Feb 13 00:00:00 GMT 2010",
>   "Challenge.Title": "net.Partner", "Challenge.CompositeId":
>   "Id=3_Tenant=103", "Challenge.Code": "2010/001"....

I have the json like text based..i want for example:

```
Challenge.Closed : false
....
Idea.id: 4
...
```

and access some of the tags that i know that exists, like id.. 
Do i have to map it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little closer to the solution, i've found the way to retrive the values, for example to entity Challenge:

```
this.responseList.Challenges["0"]["Challenge.Code"]
```

gives me the challenge code.

But instead of challenge it can be whatever, that's the name of entity, for example Ideas:

```
this.responseList.Ideas["0"]["Idea.Code"]
```

gives me the idea code.

if i want to know the names of each entity:

```
this.responseList
 >{Challenges: Array(13), Ideas: Array(1)}
```

The test was made on console with a debugger in the 'for loop' inside the code that follows:

**html**  -  Im just printing Challenges, but i neves knwo what entity i have.. it can me Ideas, or other..

```
<ul *ngFor="let res of responseList.Challenges">
   <li> {{res | json}} </li>
</ul>
```

**Component.ts**

```
public entity = [];         //has the entity names ideias, challenges whatever...
public responseList = "";   //the json that comes from the server

ngOnInit() {

   let settings = {
       "async": true,
       "crossDomain": true,
       "url": "ip/to/api",
       "method": "POST",
       "data": "\"dataApi\"",
   };

   $.ajax(settings).done((rest) => this.response(rest));

}

 response(res){

this.responseList = res; //the json file with allt he information

      for(let i in res)
      {
         //array with all entities inside json
         this.entity.push(i);
      }

      debugger;
}
```

Based on that information, i have to work inside .ts with for loops and arrays and the just print the result on .html, right? Can somebody help me with that?

**Edited for solution**

If i could print the values on the console, i can print them too with my previous for loop:

**component.ts:**
    for(let i in res)
    {
          for(let j in res[i])
              {
                  this.singleArray.push({
                  tag: i,
                  value: val
              });

```
         for(let t in res[i][j])
         {    
             this.singleArray.push({
             tag: t,
             value: this.responseList[i][j][t]
         });

         if(t.split(".",2)[1] === "CompositeId")
         {
          this.singleArray.push({
          tag: "URL:",
          value: this.moduleName + "/" + t.split(".",2)[0] + "/" + this.responseList[i][j][t].match(/=(.*)_/)[1]
          });
        }
     }
   }
}
```

with that 'for loop' i can get the tag and the value:
to print them on html side:

**html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of singleArray">
   <li>
     {{item.tag}} - {{item.value}}
   </li>
   <a *ngIf="item.tag.includes('URL')"> <a href="{{item.value}}"><li>- LINK -</li></a></a>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

So i think i am close, i know that with {{res | json }} i can print all the data and tags, including curly braces etc from the json file. (its like a json file to text)

But i need to print only the entity: tags and values. keep in mind that i neves know what comes on the json file. Here's what i have so far:

```
public entity = [];
public cont = [];
```

.Created and array and pushes all the entities:

```
this.res = response;
for(let i in response)
{
   //array with entities inside json
   this.entity.push(i);
}
return this.res;
```

the on the **html** side i can get:

```
<!-- all the data from json-->
     <ng-container>
       <li>{{res}}</li>
     </ng-container>

<!-- all the Challenges or whatever comes after res --- res.HERE-->
      <ng-container>
        <li>{{res.Challenges | json}}</li>
      </ng-container>


<!-- or (example with Ideas)-->
      <ng-container *ngFor="let x of res.Ideas">
         <li>{{x | json}}</li>
      </ng-container>


<!-- print all the entities that come in the json 
(challenges, Ideas, whatever.. that goes with res.HERE)-->
       <ng-container *ngFor="let i of entity">
         <li>{{i}}</li>
       </ng-container>
```

so, i can get the **entities**, each entity has its own attributes, for example to entity **Challenges**:

```
Challenge.Closed
Challenge.EndSubmissionDate
Challenge.Title
etc..
```

but how can i acess the values to each attribute? with the html i've posted i can get what's inside the coments, so i could iterate each entity like:

```
<!-- json file has 2 entities -->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let i of entity">
        <!-- trying to print res.Challenges and res.Ideas -->
         <ng-container *ngFor="let jsn of res.i">
             <li>{{jsn | json}}</li>
         </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
```

but, no success. i don't see how can i solve it! 
with that for loop i've posted earlier:

```
for(let i in response)
{
  this.cont.push(i);
    for(let j in response[i])
    {
      this.cont.push(j);
          for(let t in response[i][j])
          {
            this.cont.push(t);
          }
    }
}
```

I've printed on the html side:

[image: html side printes for loop]

the best thing was to get the values for each "entity.attribute" and not only the tags like i have (showed on the image)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

all you have to do is to loop through response

**.HTML**

```
<div  class="div1">
  <ul class="r " *ngFor="let res of responseList.challenges">
    <li>
     {{res.closed}} 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**.TS**

```
public responseList = "";
ngOnInit() {

let settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "url": "ip/to/api",
          "method": "POST",
          "data": "\"dataApi\"",
      };

    $.ajax(settings).done() = (res) => this.response(res);

response(res){
    console.log(res);
      this.responseList = res;
    }
```

Comment: But how to pass response to html side?  i can't reach it on html side..

Comment: you need to assign it, create a local variable and then when you get response you assign the data to that

Comment: yes, i've done that already, but no success. 
on the html side it can't reach the response. and i never know what comes on the json. i just want to diusplay all on html, the tags and te data atached to that tags 

example: 

Challenge.Closed: false 
...
Idea.Code: 15-2541
...

Comment: I can get the actual data with the pipe json {{ res | json }} but retrieves me json like text, with curly braces and everything.. i've updates my  original post with some information of what im trying to archive.. let me know if you can help me.  thank you

Comment: The reason that your not able to access is that its in callback function so you need to get it out of callback function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback refer this

Comment: I've done what yiu say: my code looks like:
..
$.ajax(settings).done((res) => this.response(res));
}
response(res){
        console.log(res);
        this.responseList = res;
    }

and on my html is doesn't display nothing.. and no error on console..

Comment: I just cant access any particular tag... as you see i can only print all the file. I just want to print the tag = value.. it can't be that hard.. but i fint it impossible now..  this.responseList = res; has the exact same content as this.res! i dont see any difference..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the $.ajax() `context` object here like:

```
let settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "url": "ip/to/api",
          "context": this,
          "method": "POST",
          "data": "\"dataApi\"",
      };
```

Comment: I've added the context, but i can get the results on console.log(response), the problmes is iterate over it, and get the actual results on for loop, i can't access them, only the tags,,

Comment: you are doing ```this.res = response;``` so you can access res in your html, whats the problem? i don't get.

Comment: I can get the output on the html side, but onçly the tags like:
Challenge.Code.. But not the actual code that comes with that.. 
I want Challenge.Code : 12-251

my {{res}} on html retrieves me this:

[object Object]Challenges - 0 : Challenge.Closed Challenge.EndSubmissionDate Challenge.Title Challenge.CompositeId Challenge.Code Challenge.Description Challenge.EntryDate
........

Comment: add json pipe: ```{{res|json}}```

Comment: yes, it prints all the text present on json file (i've done this.res = JSON.stringify(response) ), with curly braces and braces and everyting, i want to print it clear, like i do with my for loop on console, is it possible? 
Challenge.Closed": false
"Challenge.EndSubmissionDate": "Sat Feb 13 00:00:00 GMT 2010"
"Challenge.Title": "net.Partner"
...

my actual output it:
{ "Challenges": [ { "Challenge.Closed": false, "Challenge.EndSubmissionDate": "Sat Feb 13 00:00:00 GMT 2010", "Challenge.Title": "net.Partner", "Challenge.CompositeId": "Id=3_Tenant=103",.....